# How to keep the if statement hidden when starting pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm not sure how to write that down but i'll do my best.
I have some program with "a lot" of code inside - if statements -.
To be able to read better my code i always use the pycharm option to "reduce the loop" like there is a small "+" or "-" icon next to each if/while/etc.. loop to hide the indented code inside.

My problem is that every time i re-open pycharm everything is open and i need to click on every little "-" to hide it again.

I've tried to look in the options but couldn't find anything related to that .. 
Maybe you can help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: The term you want to look for is: Code folding. There are options in Pycharm in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding` but I fear none of them will cover your specific needs. Maybe try to tick in `Custom folding regions`, I am not sure how this option works.